# spring boot MVC: how to redirect to a view

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I try to do a java web application using SpringBoot and the MVC pattern.
How to redirect to a view (html page) from this kind of function located in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/authentification", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void logData(LoginForm lgf){
        if(diaDao.loggin(lgf.getMail(), lgf.getMdp()))
            //home
        else
            //loginPage
 
    }
```

Comment: You don't as you are using `@ResponseBody` the result will be converted to JSON/XML or whatever is being used.

Comment: You can use `ModelAndView` for redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you won't be able to redirect to a page this way, you're returning the body of a response. you must not include @ResponseBody in the method signature, so that spring understands that it should look for a page.

your method needs to be like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/authentification", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String logData(LoginForm lgf){
    if(diaDao.loggin(lgf.getMail(), lgf.getMdp()))
        return "page_name";
    else
        return "page_name";

}
```

you can also use ModelAndView to redirect to a page and still send data to the page. thus:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/authentification", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView logData(LoginForm lgf){
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page_name1");
    if(diaDao.loggin(lgf.getMail(), lgf.getMdp())) {
        mv.addObject("objectX", "objectValueX");
    } else {
        mv.setViewName("page_name2");
        mv.addObject("objectY", "objectValueY");
    }
    return mv;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help
I will use the "ModelAndView" because I use intellIj and the community edition doesn't work well with jsp